# Import error in pdfminer3k

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed pdfminer3k on a linux machine with python 3.2.2 version. When I try to run the pdf2text.py file, I am gettin the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/pdf2txt.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf
ImportError: No module named 'pdfminer'
```

Can anyone tell why is this error encountered?

Comment: How are you running `pdf2text.py` ? My guess would be that it defines a `/usr/bin/python` shebang, defaulting in a `python2.X` instead of the 3.2.2 version. Try using `python3.2 pdf2text.py` to see if that solves your problem.

Comment: The shebang defined is #!/usr/bin/env python3.Which is python 3 compatible.